# Gurux on Bluetooth IGXMedia with Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, bluetooth

I'm trying to communicate with a Bluetooth Optical Probe using a SPP (serial port) that is attached to a smart meter. I have seen that using the Gurux software will be a good idea. However, they do not offer native support for Bluetooth communication (other than in the Python example) and their mobile support is only for Android-Java. Has anyone managed to create an instance of IGXMedia within Gurux for Bluetooth? The Gurux BTSerial class uses `System.IO.Ports.SerialPort` which is only available on Windows, where I am trying to use Cross-Platform C#.

Comment: I''d suggest you ask this on their forums - https://www.gurux.fi/node/5655.  It's not really suited for SO.

Comment: Thanks Jason, I have asked on their forum for this, but haven't had too much activity so was trying another platform to see if there is anyone else who has used it or has any insight.